# Nilpotent differential operators of degree $2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've reflecting about global solvability of a class of (pseudo-)differential operators.

In the middle of my researchs a condition like $P^2=0$ appeared where $P$ is a differential operator. However, this condition sounds a bit restrictive. So, I'm wondering, are there (interesting) examples of differential operators whose square is $0$?

Thanks.

Comment: You want a differential operator for which every sufficiently differentiable function is a solution?

Comment: Indeed, I'm just looking for a differential operator whose square is zero (so I would be able to verify the conclusions I got aren't void but at first it seems it was).

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): The answer is _Yes_ in the context of [supernumbers](http://planetmath.org/supernumber) and [Grassmann-numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number). If $P$ is a Grassmann-odd operator such operator has several applications. E.g. the [Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) is based on a Grassmann-odd second-order differential operator $\Delta$ that squares to zero, often called the _odd Laplacian._